# Publishing ros topics with Pixy

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , I was wondering how i can publish topics and view them using rostopic from Pixy. What i am trying to do is , I would like pixy to publish data of it's signatures and view it using the rostopic echo command. However, I am stuck in trying to show the signature as I am not sure how to write the arduino code for it. So , can anyone please walk me through this process? I am completely lost.
Thanks in advance,
Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174058/publishing-ros-topics-with-pixy/) by [manaXmizery](https://answers.ros.org/users/9931/manaxmizery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may wish to follow the progress of [THIS OTHER THREAD](http://answers.ros.org/question/165396/how-to-get-the-pixy-camera-working-on-ros/) that may help you answer parts of your question.

I think that if not done already, you could learn much by some self-training and you may find the answer there easier.
Best to start at the very beginning which would be ...   [The ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)

There is a wealth of info in the tutorials that is the foundation for all ROS discussions.  My own experience has shown me that to get ROS fully running and to mess with it yourself requires hours of learning-by-doing so the tutorials were a gold mine but do require an investment in time.  Go for it.

---

Originally posted by [mjstn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20073/mjstn/) with karma: 31 on 2014-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0